# Look if a string starts with the ending characters of another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to see if ending of one string is similar to starting of another string

if i have a string 
`a="12345678"` and
`b="56789"`
i want to update a as 123456789

these two strings are in a list

```
s="12345678"
b="56789"
```

o/p:

```
s=123456789
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
s="12345678"
b="56789"
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == b[0]:
        if s[i::] in b[0:len(s[i::])]:
            print('Found')
```

This works even if the string `s` repeats. What I am doing is going around, for the length of `s` and then seeing if `s[i]` is equal to the first char in `b`. I then look to see if the rest of `s` is, either `b` or is in `b`.

Comment: Noobie (and also not OP) but what kind of slicing is that in the second if statement (the s[i::])

Answer (score 0):

You can for how long the two match, and concatenate from there:

```py
s="12345678"
b="156789"


longest_match = 0
for i in range(1, min(len(s), len(b))):
    if s[-i:] == b[:i]:
        longest_match = i

if longest_match > 0:
    o = s + b[longest_match:]
    print(o)
```