# How to find the longest common suffix prefix between two strings in python in a pythonic way possibly using library functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two strings, `s1 = "1234"` and `s2 ="34567"`, so longest common suffix prefix between `s1` and `s2` is `"34"`. I want to know if there exists any pythonic way to get this matching part (`"34"`) real quick.

I can do it in a naive way like this one below, but I would love to know if there is an interesting library function or algorithm to get this done.

```py
s1 = "1234"
s2 = "34567"
length1 = len(s1) 
length2 = len(s2)

length = (length1 if length1<= length2 else length2)

for i in reversed(range(0, length)):
    if s1[-i - 1:] == s2[:i + 1]:
        print(s1[-i - 1:])
        break
    elif i > 0:
        continue
    else:
        print("no common suffix prefix")
```

Output:

```
34
```

I want something compact and smart!

Comment: your solution seems the most logical, I don't think there are any existing libraries because the problem is so small and fixable and is so highly specific no-one who has solved it before has thought that anyone else might need it. If you wanted to create and upload a pip package and link this question to it it might be useful for you and for others in the future. Up to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Look if a string starts with the ending characters of another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794780/look-if-a-string-starts-with-the-ending-characters-of-another-string)

Comment: @ChrisOliver The solution in the link is somewhat interesting but I was looking for a library function that can handle this smartly.

Comment: However, @Alexander Bielby 's comment tells me why such a solution does not exist.

Comment: @Rubel. Doesn't mean you shouldn't have a grain of salt with that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your algorithm is about as straightforward as you can get, but you can definitely compactify the notation. For example, checking a prefix of size `n` against a suffix of size `n` is simply:

```
s1[-n:] == s2[:n]
```

The ternary operator you use to check string lengths is

```
min(len(s1), len(s2))
```

A range can go backwards by itself. The reverse of `range(x)` is

```
range(x - 1, -1, -1)
```

You can create an iterator that checks this for each decreasing value of `n` and return the first non-zero result. Luckily, `next` accepts a second argument that represents the default if the iterator is empty:

```
common = next((s2[:n] for n in range(min(len(s1), len(s2)) - 1, -1, -1) if s1[-n:] == s2[:n]), '')
```

That's the obligatory one-liner. A more legible solution might be:

```
def common_fix(s1, s2):
    steps = range(min(len(s1), len(s2)) - 1, -1, -1)
    return next((s2[:n] for n in steps if s1[-n:] == s2[:n]), '')
```

As a rule, keep your functionally and printing separate. Get a value, then process it (whether by printing or something else)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple alternative implementations:

You know that the suffix of `s1` must start with `s2[0]`.  So use `s1.find(s[0])` to find candidate starting points.  Also, `s2.startswith()` can be used instead of iterating over `s2`.  I don't know if it is faster, but the intent is clear.

```
def suffix_prefix_1(s1, s2):
    i = s1.find(s2[0])
    while i >= 0:
        if s2.startswith(s1[i:]):
            return s1[i:]

        i = s1.find(s2[0], i+1)

    return ''
```

If you're using Python 3.8, the walrus operator lets you write it like this:

```
def suffix_prefix_1A(s1, s2):
    while (i := s1.find(s2[0])) >= 0:
        if s2.startswith(s1[i:]):
            return s1[i:]

    return ''
```

The same thing can be done using `s1.endswith()`:

```
def suffix_prefix_2(s1, s2):
    e= len(s2)
    while e > 0:
        if s1.endswith(s2[:e]):
            return s2[:e]
        e = s2.rfind(s1[-1], 0, e-1) + 1

    return ''
```

And just for fun, let's use a regex:

```
import re

def suffix_prefix_3(s1, s2):
    match = re.search(f"^{'?'.join(s1)}", s2)
    return match[0] if match else ''
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
s1="1234"
s2="34567"
for i in range(len(s1)):
    if s1[i] == s2[0]:
        if s1[i::] in s2[0:len(s1[i::])]:
            print(s1[i::])
```

The `for` loop finds the length of `s1`. It then iterates for that length. If `s1[i]` is then equal to the start of `s2`, it checks to see if `s1[i::]` is in `s2`. If this is then true, it prints out `s1[i::]`

Comment: I have found a solution for that now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, I have found a solution for that to. It should now work for any input

Comment: You'd want to use `startswith`, not `in`